# How get raw response (array of parameters) in POST method in SpringMVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I pass a reference third-party system and this system return me some parameters but I not understand What are the parameters. It is my controller with POST method

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/success")
public class SuccessController {



     @RequestMapping(value = "/eventlogs/logs", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String logs(@RequestParam("Approved") String json) {
            System.out.println("Received POST request:" + json);

            return "success";
        }
    }
```

But I not understand how type parameters I get/ I my example I wait  parameter  `"Approved"` and type `String`
But How can I get raw  response in my method? for example like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/success")
public class SuccessController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/eventlogs/logs", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String logs(HttpResponse response) {
    System.out.println("Received POST request:" + response.get("p1"));
    System.out.println("Received POST request:" + response.get("p2"));
    System.out.println("Received POST request:" + response.get("p3"));
    ....
            return "success";
        }
    }
```

I know that third-party system set to my method many parameters and I do not want write something like

```
public String logs(@RequestParam("p1") String p1, @RequestParam("p2") int p2, @RequestParam("p3") boolean p3 .......)
```

I want something like JavaEE servlet's method

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
 resp.get(......)
        super.doPost(req, resp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `HttpServletRequest` (not `HttpServletResponse`) as parameter:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/success")
public class SuccessController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/eventlogs/logs", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String logs(HttpServletRequest req) {
        System.out.println("Received POST request:" + req.getParameter("..."));
....
        return "success";
    }
}
```

To know all the parameters sent in a request, use [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterNames`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames--) or [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap--) to evaluate each parameter and its value or values.

Comment: A better plan is to not use HttpServletRequest and use org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest instead so you are not tied to the native servlet/portlet API.

Comment: @DwB after some research I've found something better and closed this question as a duplicate. Sadly, since this is the accepted answer I can't delete it.